# How to split pyodbc.row into a list of its values

Tags: python, sql, database

I am trying to call a single column from my SQL server and then split it at each "," so I have a list of all the fields in this column
I currently have this code:

> for element in tagall:
>           parts = element.split(',')
>           print (parts)

but this returns that

> 'pyodbc.row has no attribute 'split'

Is there any way to split the row into separate lines?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to print this out as a big string instead of keeping the items separate.

for that you can do:

```
for element in tagall:
    print(",".join(element))
```

if you wanted to split it in to separate lines you could do

```
for element in tagall:
    for item in element:
        print(item) #but this doesn't need a comma because they are on separate lines
```

Comment: I'm using tkinter module to display these but when I want to split these onto separate lines the label I want to display the separate elements only shows the last element. What should I do to make it display all the elements

Comment: Can you post an example of "element"?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are trying to split the row object, which is kinda like a list. so if you're only getting one column back you need to do something like:

```
row[0].split(',')
```